# How to create a new file which provides filename and its source directory information

Tags: bash, scripts, xubuntu, lubuntu

I have a directory that contains so many sub directories and files in them. I would like to create a file which provides each file name and it's source directory path information

For example:

- I have a folder name sample which contains sample1 and sample2 sub
  directories in it
- I have ex1.csv, ex2.csv in sample 1 and ex3.csv, ex4.csv in sample
  2 directory

I need to create a text file (or) csv file which gives the information in the following manner

ex1.csv,sample/sample1

ex2.csv,sample/sample1

ex3.csv,sample/sample2

It would be great if someone help me out to create the script file in unix

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried the `tree` command in terminal?

Comment: I am working in Solaris UNIX environment, tree command is not working

Comment: Crossposted on Unix.SE - [How to create a new file which provides filename and its source directory information](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/306575)

Answer (score 1):

Given a structure like

```
$ tree sample
sample
├── sample1
│   ├── ex1.csv
│   └── ex2.csv
└── sample2
    ├── ex3.csv
    └── ex4.csv

2 directories, 4 files
```

you can use

```
$ find sample -type f -printf '%f,%h\n'
ex2.csv,sample/sample1
ex1.csv,sample/sample1
ex3.csv,sample/sample2
ex4.csv,sample/sample2
```

From `man find`, the relevant `-printf` format specifiers are

```
       %f     File's  name  with  any leading directories removed (only
              the last element).

       %h     Leading directories of file's name (all but the last ele‐
              ment).  If the file name contains no slashes (since it is
              in the current directory) the  %h  specifier  expands  to
              ".".
```

If you want the results in a file, just redirect the command output using the `>` operator e.g.

```
find sample -type f -printf '%f,%h\n' > filelist
```

Comment: Can u provide the information about to create a file with the required information
I cannot use tree command and i don't have privileges to install tree command

Comment: @vinodkumar just redirect the command output to a file using the `>` operator e.g. `find sample -type f -printf '%f,%h\n' > somefile`

Comment: After running the comment i am getting "bad option printf find: [-H | -L] path-list predicate list error "

Comment: @vinodkumar the `find` command on Solaris does not behave exactly the same as the one on Linux systems, as you have just discovered - that's why we have OS specific forums